# Call rails "posts#show" action with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is my index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <li>
            <%= post.title %> <%= post.author %>
            <%= link_to "show", post_path(post) %>
        </li>
<% end %>
```

I click the "show" anchor and it goes to the show.html.erb for the post. But I don't want an anchor, I just want to be able to click the post itself and go to the show page. What's an easy way of implementing this?

Comment: can you be more explicit about this? I am getting the idea that you want to use title as a link to your posts. Is this what you want?

Comment: wrap the content of the post in a link

Comment: I want the whole <li></li> to be a clickable item that goes to its show.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you mean the `title` and `author` when you say `the post itself`. If so, this should do it:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
            <%= post.title %> <%= post.author %>
        <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it.
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
            <li>
                <%= post.title %> <%= post.author %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

Answer (score 1):

You can add `onclick` event to the `li`

```
<li onclick='window.location = "/posts/#{post.id}"'>
  <%= post.title %> <%= post.author %>
</li>
```

**or**, you can wrap the content of the post in a link

```
= link_to "#{post.title} #{post.author}", post_path(post)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to click the link, but instead you want to click the whole item?

You could assign an onClick-Event to the whole item (your post), and fire your request from there. You can also change your mouse pointer using CSS while hovering the post to simulate a clickable area.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I mean, but I don't know the syntax of how I would link the onClick event to the rails controller action.